# Compose HorizontalPager nested scroll problem with WebView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview

I am trying to use Webview with HorizontalPager (New one), if the webview content size is more than the screenWidth, it will get an internal scroll but HorizontalPager doesn’t respect that.

The only way to scroll webview is if u use two fingers and drag around.
Tried using `

> rememberNestedScrollInteropConnection()

` but no luck.

Tested the same behaviour in XML with ViewPager , works without any problem(it will scroll the webview until u have reached to the end after which it will scroll the pager,just like how it should be.)

Looking for some guidance.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "(New one)". Can you post a code snippet that exemplifies how you try to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `TouchListener` for your Webview, Then call back for your Compose Function. In Compose, check if Webview's MotionEvent is `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` then disable your Pager's `userScrollEnabled`, Such as `HorizontalPager` by set `userScrollEnabled = false`. And if Webview's MotionEvent is `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, then enable your Pager's `userScrollEnabled`.

For example, In my Webview.kt:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CustomWebView(
    // ...
    onTouchEvent: ((event: MotionEvent) -> Boolean)? = null
){
    AndroidView(factory = { ctx ->
        WebView(ctx).apply {
            // ...

            if (onTouchEvent != null) {
                setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
                    onTouchEvent(event)
                }
            }
            // ...
        }
    })
}
```

In my Main.kt which call `CustomWebView` with `HorizontalPager`:

```kotlin
// ...

private fun MainContent(
    pagerState: PagerState,
    navController: NavHostController,
    scaffoldState: BottomSheetScaffoldState,
    gesturesEnabled: Boolean,
    onChangeGesturesEnabled: (enable: Boolean) -> Unit
) {

    var userScrollEnabled by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }


    HorizontalPager(
        pageCount = 3,
        state = pagerState,
        userScrollEnabled = userScrollEnabled
    ) { page ->
        when (page) {
            0 -> DynamicContent(scaffoldState, navController)
            1 -> RecommendContent(scaffoldState, navController)
            2 -> MyContent(scaffoldState, navController) {
                ouserScrollEnabled = it
            }
        }
    }
}

//...

fun MyContent(
    scaffoldState: BottomSheetScaffoldState,
    navController: NavHostController,
    onEnablePagerScroll: (enable: Boolean) -> Unit
) {

// ...


   CustomWebView(
    // ...
    onTouchEvent = {
        when (it.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                onEnablePagerScroll?.invoke(false)
                false
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                onEnablePagerScroll?.invoke(true)
                false
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                onEnablePagerScroll?.invoke(true)
                false
            }
            else -> {
                false
            }
        }
    }
)
}
```

You can check full code in [github](https://github.com/equationl/githubAppByCompose/), Specific file: [WebView.kt](https://github.com/equationl/githubAppByCompose/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/equationl/githubapp/ui/common/WebView.kt) and [Person.kt](https://github.com/equationl/githubAppByCompose/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/equationl/githubapp/ui/view/person/Person.kt)'s function `PersonHeader`